# ListBox.SelectedItem vs ListBox.Items(SelectedIndex)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

I am trying to change the data of the `ListBox` item, when I have made changes and committed them to the database. However, assigning a new value to a `ListBox.SelectedItem` doesn't seem to work, but if I use `ListBox.Items(lstAlbums.SelectedIndex)` then it appears to change the actual data in my form.

I have also tested objects via `GetHashCode` and they appear to have it the same. `Boolean` is also true if I try to compare them. Does anybody know why is this happening? Below is the part of my code:

```
Private Sub DataUpdatedCallback(ByVal updatedAlbum As Album)
    ' ( lstAlbums.Items(lstAlbums.SelectedIndex) Is _
    '                           lstAlbums.SelectedItem ) == TRUE
    ' for some reason using lstAlbums.SelectedItem doesn't change the object data
    lstAlbums.Items(lstAlbums.SelectedIndex) = updatedAlbum
End Sub
```

Comment: hello sir, try to read about http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0):

Use [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) instead. Your underlying object usually has a key field that you can use for this purpose. Make sure you have set [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) property accordingly.

Comment: for which purpose? I need the whole item object to be updated, not just a single property which would be set by a `ValueMember`

Comment: @NullPointerException: If you are using data binding, UI should be updated automatically. ListBox was not meant to have data updated directly. It is for the user to make a selection. If your selection changes, you re-assign the whole DataSource. If you want updates shown in UI, you should be using [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The reference handed to `.SelectedItem` must be one of the existing items in the list, you can't use the property to modify the contents of `.Item`. Your current code

`lstAlbums.Items(lstAlbums.SelectedIndex) = updatedAlbum`

is correct.

Comment: Could you be more clear? 'must be one of the existing items in the list' - it is, but `Items(lstAlbums.SelectedIndex)` appears exactly the same. So if it is the design flow that the current selected item object could be reassigned, am I doing smth wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that `updatedAlbum` is a copy of the object in the list rather than a reference to the actual list item?

Comment: That's the problem then. `updatedAlbum` must be an already existing entry that is already inside `lstAlbums.Item()`

You cannot use `lstAlbums.SelectedItem` to replace an item in the list, you can only use it to change the selection to a different item that is already in the list.